# Microsoft.owin.testing registering IHttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an IHttpModule responsible for appending data to a header. While working on component tests using Microsoft.Owin.Testing, I'm facing challenges registering my module. I intend to write a test to verify that the header has been appropriately appended. Although I'm aware of attribute filters as a potential solution, I need to use `IHttpModule` for my specific use case.

```
MyModule : IHttpModule {
   private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {} // i want this method to run
}

// Owin setup looks like this 

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   var config = new HttpConfiguration();
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

  config.Filters.Add(new MyFilter());

   app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```